# SharePoint Online 365 event logs

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office-365-developer

I want to read event log for my SharePoint Online Server

On submitting Form getting error:

```
An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.
Log ID:5337
Correlation ID:f90c3a9d-7040-2000-1f64-d4986ff4d91d
```

Is there any standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably also also logging details to ULS, so you can use PowerShell to view that log based on the correlation ID like this:

```
$endTimeinUTC = Get-SPOTenantLogLastAvailableTimeInUtc
$startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays (-14)
$tenantlogs = Get-SPOTenantLogEntry -StartTimeinUtc $startTimeinUTC -EndTimeinUTC $endTimeinUTC -CorrelationId e2c2be70-6382-4ce7-8a44-ae7dadff5597
```

This will retrieve log entries recorded over that previous 14 days that have the CorrelationId of "e2c2be70-6382-4ce7-8a44-ae7dadff5597".

Comment: I tried this command and got no results

Comment: hi Kannan; did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to raise a service request to contact Office 365 support. See these for more info:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2694621
http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenkumar/archive/2013/07/18/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support.aspx